# Session not getting initialized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

I've been trying for the last 4 days to understand what has happened so that session isn't getting initialized anymore.

My app was working just fine, until one day suddenly i started having the error

> undefined local variable or method `session' for < StaticPagesController:0x7c84728 >

I debugged it and tracked it down to `request_forgery_protection.rb` file, under `action_controller\metal`.

```
def form_authenticity_token
  session[:_csrf_token] ||= SecureRandom.base64(32)
end
```

So, apparently, session wasn't being loaded.

I then tried suggestions from [How force that session is loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14665275/1461972), as you may see below.

```
def root

  if signed_in?
    ...
  else 
    session[:init] = true
    session[:init]
    @prospect = Prospect.new()
    render 'retailers/retailers_home'
  end
end
```

but still the same error keeps showing up.

Under my intializers, session_store.rb, everything seems fine :

```
RecibosOnline::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_RecibosOnline_session'
```

as this exact code works on other developer's machine, as well as on other server.
So this must be something specific to my machine...but why??

What might be causing this?

Comment: If it's working elsewhere, are you using git?  A `git clean -fdx` to remove everything other than committed source code is worth a quick shot.

Comment: Maybe you are using private browsing and disabled cookie?

Comment: @NickVeys, want to write that as an answer? ;-). You saved my week. Thank you.

Comment: Hah, certainly. :)  Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When all else fails and nothing makes sense anymore, reset the world:

```
git clean -fdx
```