# How To Setup Minimalist Authentication In Rails with React?

Tags: reactjs, session, authentication, cookies, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to set up a minimal layer of authentication between my Rails backend and my React front end, but I am running into some problems.

1. I cannot seem to find the cookie key value that the server passes down to my client. In the network tab, I see it in the response: `Set-Cookie:_skillcoop_session=....`, but when I use `js-cookie` to look for the above cookie, `_skillcoop_session`, I only see one called `identity-token=...` and its value is different from `_skillcoop_session`. How do I access `_skillcoop_session` in the browser?
2. What header key do I pass up to the server to signal to my backend to use 'this' header key to match up with the session it has stored off? In [this post](https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/how-rails-sessions-work/), Justin Weiss seems to suggest that I make the request to the server with a header like: `Cookie: _skillcoop_session=....`
3. Am I doing this all wrong? Would I be better off using a gem like [devise](https://rubygems.org/gems/devise/versions/4.2.0)?
4. Also in order to load the session in my other controllers, I have had to do something like `session['init'] = true`, and I learned to do this from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665275/how-force-that-session-is-loaded). This seems hacky. Why do I have to manually reload the session in separate controller actions after I've set it previously in a different controller action in a different request?

I'm currently just stubbing out the user and the authentication -- all I want to do to get the plumping in place is set a `session[:user_id]` and be able to read that session data in other controller actions. For this I have two main files for consideration: `UsersController` and `Transport.js`. In `UsersController` I am just stubbing the `session[:user_id]` with the number 1 and in `Transport.js` I'd like to pass the cookie received from the server so that the backend can maintain a session between requests with a client.

Here is my controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def create
    session[:user_id] = 1
    render json: user_stub, status: :ok
  end

  def show
    puts "user id: #{session[:user_id]}"
    # should return, 1, but is returning, nil...why?
    render json: user_stub, status: :ok
  end

  private

  def user_stub
    {
      id: 1,
      email: params['email'] || 'fakeemail@gmail.com',
      password: params['password'] || 'fake password'
    }
  end
end
```

Here is the main location of my app where I make my request to the server - it's in an abstraction I call Transport.js:

```
require('es6-promise').polyfill();
require('isomorphic-fetch');
var cookie = require('js-cookie');


const GET = 'GET';
const POST = 'POST';

function Transport() {
}

Transport.prototype.get = function(url, options = {}) {
  return this.query(GET, url, null, options);
};

Transport.prototype.post = function(url, dataString, options = {}) {
  return this.query(POST, url, dataString, options);
};

Transport.prototype.query = function(method, url, dataString, options = {}) {
  var data;

  if (dataString) {
    data = JSON.parse(dataString);
  }

  switch(method) {
    case GET:
      return fetch(url, Object.assign({headers: {'Cookie': cookie.get('_skillcoop_session')}}, options, {
        method: method
      }));
    case POST:
      return fetch(url, Object.assign({
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      }, options, {
        method: method
      }));
    default:
      throw new Error("This HTTP Method is not supported.");
  }
};

module.exports = Transport;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. According to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29895569/get-and-store-cookie-from-set-cookie-from-an-ajax-post-response), one cannot access the `Set-Cookie` header in JS. Thus, I suppose my attempts to handle `Set-Cookie` in the response headers was a fools effort.
2. [According to](https://github.com/github/fetch#caveats) the NPM package that I'm using to make HTTP requests, I need to pass `{credentials: 'same-origin'}` key value pair in the second argument to `fetch`, which will 'automatically send cookies for the current domain'. That did the trick -- the session object is available and contains the `user_id` that was set in the session in the previous request in a different action.
3. Yes. I changed up how I approached this problem. I leaned very heavily on this [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/6gisgf/how_to_build_authentication_for_rails_api_and/). In short, I use [ruby-jwt](https://rubygems.org/gems/jwt/versions/1.5.4) on the backend and store the token in `localStorage` on the front end. Each request out to the server will include the token in a header `AUTHORIZATION`.
4. In following steps 1 and 2, it looks like I no longer have to 'reload the session'.