# How retrieve session store from inside ActionCable::Connection::Base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

From action cable documentation I read this example for setting current_user:

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

  def connect
    self.current_user = find_verified_user
  end

  private
    def find_verified_user
      if verified_user = User.find_by(id: cookies.signed[:user_id])
        verified_user
      else
        reject_unauthorized_connection
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I don't have user_id cookie set because authentication is made for a cas server, and it store session in Active Record.
How tell to Connection class the current user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to force the session to load. Check this link here (worked for me): [How force that session is loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665275/how-force-that-session-is-loaded)