# Session in not persisting in rails 2.3.5 on localhost(windows 7)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I've a ruby on rails project 2.3.5 which is working fine on server.Now I need to do setup on **localhost**.But the issue is session is not saving .Whenever I try to access **session value or current_user**, it returns nil.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you facing the same issue as here so you need to force load the session:

[Rails 2.3 session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035933/rails-2-3-session)